# React Native: useEffect not firing when I navigate to already active screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native app, when I click on a notification I navigate to a chat screen, in that chat screen I have a useEffect that fetches the chat messages, problem is, if chat screen was the last opened screen before closing the app, the useEffect doesn't fire.

Funny thing is, I tried to use isFocused but it's not firing either!

Any idea how I can handle this?

```
useEffect(() => 
    {
        Alert.alert('FETCHING');
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        if(isFocused)
        {
            Alert.alert('FETCHING');
        }
    }, [isFocused]);
```

Is this the default bhaviour when navigating to a screen after clicking on a notification?

```
import { navigationRef, isReadyRef, navigate } from '@env/RootNavigation.js';

handleBackgroundNotificationClicked(data)
    {
        let notifData = JSON.parse(data.data.data);
        this.initChat(notifData.chat,false);
        navigate('ChatList', { chatId : notifData.chat.id });
    }
```

Comment: have you tried loggin isFocused so that you can identify weather isFocused is changing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useFocusEffect that is built into react-navigation like this

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
           // Fetch chat messages here
           Alert.alert('FETCHING');
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation])
);
```

It will trigger every time the screen is opened

Comment: Israel useFocusEffect On navigation 5?